# Alterar divs com a mesma classe

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="valor"> 33</td>
        <td class="valor"> 88</td>
        <td class="valor"> 55</td>
        <td class="valor"> 36</td>
        <td class="valor"> 79</td>
        <td class="valor"> 35</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Preciso colocar o simbolo de porcentagem após o número

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       var valor = $('.valor').html();
       $('.valor').text(valor+'%');
    });                   
</script>
```

Tentei fazer desta forma mas ele altera todos os numeros para o primeiro valor

Comment: Você já recebeu 5 respostas. Por favor, considere escolher como certa uma delas, para ajudar outras pessoas que também tenham a mesma dúvida. Abraços.

Answer (score 6):

Tem que fazer o concat para cada um, a sugestão aqui é fazer com o [each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/):

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
       var valor = $('.valor').each(function(){
         val = $(this).html()
          $(this).html(val + '%')
       })   
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td class="valor"> 33</td>
<td class="valor"> 88</td>
<td class="valor"> 55</td>
<td class="valor"> 36</td>
<td class="valor"> 79</td>
<td class="valor"> 35</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

Algumas formas de fazer:

## 1 - Usando JQuery ([exemplo funcionando](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vXQmpb))

```
$('.valor').append('%');
```

## 2 - Usando apenas CSS ([exemplo funcionando](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ozQWWy))

```
.valor:after {
  content: "%";
}
```

Esta técnica utiliza o pseudo-elemento `::after` do CSS2.
Confira a [compatibilidade com os diferentes navegadores](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent).

## 3 - Usando apenas Javascript ([exemplo funcionando](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NREjON?editors=1010))

```
var valores = document.getElementsByClassName('valor');

for (var i=0; valores[i]; i++) {
  valores[i].innerHTML += '%';
}
```

Esta opção não precisa do JQuery, e é compatível também com alguns navegadores antigos.

Answer (score 1):

Tens que fazer esse processo para cada elemento (obj) que tem atribuída a classe referida. Podes aceder aos dados do objecto com o wrapper JQuery $(this).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('.valor').each(function(obj) {
          var valor = $(this).html();
          $(this).text(valor+'%');
       }); 
    });
</script>
```

Não testei mas acredito que será algo nestas linhas.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   var valores = $('.valor');
    for (i = 0; i < valores.length; i++) { 
        var valor = valores[i];
        valor.textContent = valor.textContent + '%';
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você deve iterar sobre todos os itens. Pode fazer isso utilizando a função  [each](https://api.jquery.com/each/). Você também pode acessar o elemento diretamente, como no código abaixo, ao invés de usar a função html().

```js
$('.valor').each(function(){
    this.innerHTML+='%';
});
```